# Saving an image to .jpg file : Java

Tags: java

The way I am saving a jFreeChart to a jpeg file is :

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
"Hysteresis Plot", // chart title
"Pounds(lb)", // domain axis label
"Movement(inch)", // range axis label
dataset, // data
PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
false, // include legend
true, // tooltips
false // urls
);
```

Then:

```
 image=chart.createBufferedImage( 300, 200);
```

The image appeas as:
[image]

My save function is:

```
public static void saveToFile(BufferedImage img)
    throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:/Sample.jpg");
        JPEGImageEncoder encoder2 =
        JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(fos);
        JPEGEncodeParam param2 =
        encoder2.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(img);
        param2.setQuality((float) 200, true);
        encoder2.encode(img,param2);
        fos.close();
    }
```

I am calling it as:

```
try{
            saveToFile(image);
           }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

The saved image appeas as:

[image]

Any suggestion, where I am wrong or how to save it the way it appears or may be I need to save as .png. Can anyone let me know how to save as .png?

Thanks

Comment: For info on saving as png, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple Solution:

```
public static void saveToFile(BufferedImage img)
    throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {

        File outputfile = new File("D:\\Sample.png");
    ImageIO.write(img, "png", outputfile);
    }
```

Saved the image, the way it appears.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather suggest that instead of using ImageIo.write in order to save your image, you better use the following function:

```
ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG("name of your file", jfreechart, lenght, width);
```

Because then you can manage the size of the picture but also save picture without filters.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great example on how this could be done.

```
File imageFile = new File("C:\\LineChart.png");
int width = 640;
int height = 480;
try {
    ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(imageFile, chart, width, height);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
}
```