# Save image inside specific folder and store path in mysql to display later

Tags: java, mysql, swing, image-processing, netbeans

For my project, I am creating an expense management system. There is a place where the user can select an image file from local disk and add it as an attachment when adding a new expense.

The uploaded image should be displayed in a jLabel and then should be saved inside the project folder (say for e.g. /src/accounts/media) when clicking the save button, and the path should be saved inside a varchar column in mysql database for later retrieval.

For now, I can upload the image and display the image in jLabel.

Can anyone help me out on how save that image file inside a folder and to store the path in database?

```
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

    FileFilter ft = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image Files", "jpg", "png", "jpeg");
    //FileFilter ft2 = new FileNameExtensionFilter("PDF Files", "pdf");

    chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(ft);
    //chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(ft2);
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    filePath = f.getAbsolutePath().toString();

    BufferedImage img = null;
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File(filePath));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Image dimg = img.getScaledInstance(lblAttachment.getWidth(), lblAttachment.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);


    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(dimg);
    lblAttachment.setText("");
    lblAttachment.setIcon(icon);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving an image to .jpg file : Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095934/saving-an-image-to-jpg-file-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy file to another location, you can choose any

[Way1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256219/copy-file-from-one-folder-to-another-in-java)

[Way2](http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/corejava/java-copy-file-from-directory-to-another.html)

To store the path, make a file-path column write insert query (SQL) :

```
prepareStatement  ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO filePath VALUES(?, ?, ?)" );

         ps.setString(1,filePath);
         ps.set..
     //  conn, connection object
```

Full tutorial [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-insert-records.htm)

**Edit:**

To save it in you some default Resources folder, You can obtain path, for EG:

```
public class ClassDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ClassDemo c = new ClassDemo();
    Class cls = c.getClass();

    // finds resource relative to the class location
    URL url = cls.getResource("file.txt");
    System.out.println("Value = " + url);

    // finds resource relative to the class location
    url = cls.getResource("newfolder/a.txt");
    System.out.println("Value = " + url);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain me how I can save the image inside a project folder using relative path option? because the project location can be varied, and I need some portability options.

I want to copy the image inside the folder /src/exp/resources

Comment: Use thefull path to your folder. Lets say `C://Users//U_name//MyDocuments//NetBeansProject.....ProjectFolderName`..

Comment: yh.. but what if the project location can be varied? If I can use a relative path like /src/resources it would be easier to save the image no matter where the project is located is. right?

Comment: Thank you. :-) I tried the FileUtils and i worked like a charm. And for relative location, I used System.getProperty("user.dir") and concatenated the rest of the path to create the filepath.